# How do i put php function inside a javascript onclick function?

Tags: php, javascript

```
$('#submit').click(function(event){
         //code to do php include(otherpage.php)
     });
```

How am i able to archieve this with a submit button with id=submit?

Comment: You need to install a php runtime with javascript bindings into your browser first to exectue PHP inside javascript.

Comment: I think you are looking for **ajax**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access PHP methods inside a Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139890/how-to-access-php-methods-inside-a-javascript)

Comment: @Sascha Galley: If you think that far, please add a duplicate as well ;)

Comment: how do i go about this the ajax for this then? I just need the page to go 2 page. One the paypal, another the php page which does database add. No values need to be send i just need it to went there as well.

Comment: If you just want to go to a different page on submit, why don't you simply put your form's ACTION parameter to where you want to go?

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript runs on the client, PHP on the server.

The only way to "call" PHP from your JavaScript is to use techniques like AJAX.